# Get data Sorted by descending size according units of measurement in SQLite

Tags: android, sorting, android-sqlite

I have a table with these column

```
|Name|Quantity|Unit
```

And I want to get the data sorted by descending size according units of measurement
for example:

```
|Bread|1.2|Kg
|Pasta|600.21|g
|Flour|200.18|g
|Salt|70.12|mg
|Pepper|60.3|mg
|Venom|700.15|mcg
```

*1.2* is minor than *600.21* but the unit is *Kg* so in the order priority is before according scale *Kg > g > mg >mcg* etc.
(assuming that the table doesn't contains 6000g because the notation is 6Kg)

This code clearly doesn't works

```
    public Cursor allDataSorted() {
        try {
            Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(
                    "SELECT * FROM myTable order by Quantity desc", null);
            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            return c;
        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "allDataSorted>>" + mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }

    }

    }
```

And all data in my table are text String so *956* for example is wrongly showed after *99*, so I have no idea of How I could solve this problem and the result is totally unsorted.

Any suggestion?

NB

I cannot convert and reconvert the tables, 
these are too big, and the adapter is used for too many kind of units to use only a general base unit.

**EDIT**

Following the suggestion of Ryan Griggs I have included *mapperTb* table in the same db file

```
Unit|Multipler
hg|100
g|1
dg|0.1
cg|0.01
mg|0.001
mcg|0.000001
```

And I have edit the allDataSorted() method in this way:

```
    public Cursor allDataSorted() {
        try {
            Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT *, (CAST(myTable.Quantity as FLOAT) * mapperTb.Multipler) as Quantity FROM myTable INNER JOIN mapperTb ON myTable.Unit = mapperTb.Unit ORDER BY Quantity desc", null);
            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            return c;
        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "allDataSorted>>" + mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }

    }

    }
```

but doesn't works and the Cursor results empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that in your sorting routine, you convert all values to a base unit (i.e. Grams).  Then you can properly sort.  You could create another table which maps each unit to the proper multiplier (i.e Kg = 1000, g = 1) and then calculate the base unit for each entry, and sort by that value.  Then you don't have to worry about things like 6000g vs 6Kg.

Example: create mapping table "unit_map" with fields 'unit' and 'multiplier'. Add all applicable units and multipliers.
So the new query becomes:

```
SELECT *, (CAST(myTable.Quantity as FLOAT) * unit_map.multiplier) as sort_field FROM myTable INNER JOIN unit_map ON myTable.Unit = unit_map.unit ORDER BY sort_field
```

Comment: Example: create mapping table "unit_map" with fields 'unit' and 'multiplier'.  Add all applicable units and multipliers.

Comment: New query would look like this:  SELECT *, (myTable.Quantity * unit_map.multiplier) as sort_field FROM myTable INNER JOIN unit_map ON myTable.Unit = unit_map.unit ORDER BY sort_field

Comment: You may need to use the CAST() function to convert the Quantity to a float.  Example: CAST(mytable.Quantity as FLOAT)

Comment: So the new query becomes: SELECT *, (CAST(myTable.Quantity as FLOAT) * unit_map.multiplier) as sort_field FROM myTable INNER JOIN unit_map ON myTable.Unit = unit_map.unit ORDER BY sort_field

Comment: I cannot convert and reconvert the table, are too big and the adapter is used for too many kind of units. In addition the values are String so 956 is showed after 99

Comment: Using the CAST notation as in my examples above you do not need to convert the table types.  This is done on-the-fly during the query execution.

Comment: Also, without some sort of mapping table for units, there is no way to know which is greater or less.  So you will need to have some sort of map which indicates the weight of each type of unit.

Comment: How many different units are in the table?  (SELECT DISTINCT Units FROM myTable) will tell you this.

Comment: there are all weight, volume units and,  as I have said, In addition the values are String so 956.3 is wrongly showed after 99.8.

Comment: But the CAST function will convert these to float so they can be sorted.  Can you explain why you are not using a CAST to eliminate this problem?

Comment: Ok, ok... now I have better understood your suggestion, Could you edit your answer with the right syntax that I should use to fix the issue, assuming that I have in the same database file another table named mapper with two columns unit and multiplier values, in addition to myTable? Thanks.

Comment: Ok,I'll try this solution and if works I'll mark your answer as accepted, in meanwhile thanks ;)

Comment: I have tried to follow your sample but doesn't works and I get a empty cursor... Look at the edit in my question

Comment: I recommend you take this to a SQL Fiddle where we can work together on it.  (http://sqlfiddle.com).  Create the fiddle and add your tables.  Send me the link and I will help you fix the SQL query.